# How can I make to signed char in C function like unsigned

Tags: c

I'm trying to encode_char_in C that replace the bit of even index between the odd bit index, like this

```
 'W' = 57h = 0101_0111
       ABh = 1010_1011
```

and because `char` in C may become to negative number, I can't switch between the bits (only in `signed char` — it works).
It gave me another value
in this code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define ONE 1

char codeBinPair(char str);

void main()
{
char str[2] = { 182,NULL };
unsigned char ch = 'W';
printf("ch = %x\n", ch);
ch = codeBinPair(ch);
printf("ch = %x\n", ch);
ch = codeBinPair(ch);
printf("ch = %x\n", ch);
}

char codeBinPair(char str)
{
    int idx = 0;
    char ch1 = str, ch2 = 0, mask = ONE;
    while (TRUE) 
    {
    mask <<= ONE;
    mask &= ch1;
    mask >>= ONE;
    ch2 |= mask;
    // Initialize the mask
    mask = ONE;
    mask <<= idx;
    mask &= ch1;
    mask <<= ONE;
    ch2 |= mask;
     // Index next loop we want to replace
     idx += 2;
     // If We Finish whole Byte
     if (idx == CHAR_BIT)
        return ch2;
     // Initialize the mask
     mask = ONE;    
     mask <<= idx;
 }
}
```

Comment: C has `signed char` and `unsigned char`, you know. If you care about doing bit math, use one of those. (Or, even better, `int_least8_t` and `uint_least8_t`.)

Comment: @cHao He seems to know, since he declared `unsigned char ch = 'W'`. So the code just needs to use `unsigned char` as the type of the argument to `codeBinPair`.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature and invokes undefined behaviour. Then don't define your own boolen constants/type, but use the standard ones! Finally, your code may invoke undefined behaviour or relies on implementation defined behaviour for some of the shifts and certain values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the `char` in `codeBinPair` to `unsigned char`.

```
unsigned char codeBinPair(unsigned char str)
{
    int idx = 0;
    unsigned char ch1 = str, ch2 = 0, mask = ONE;
    while (TRUE) 
        {
            mask <<= ONE;
            mask &= ch1;
            mask >>= ONE;
            ch2 |= mask;
            // Initialize the mask
            mask = ONE;
            mask <<= idx;
            mask &= ch1;
            mask <<= ONE;
            ch2 |= mask;
            // Index next loop we want to replace
            idx += 2;
            // If we finish whole byte
            if (idx == CHAR_BIT)
                return ch2;
            // Initialize the mask
            mask = ONE;    
            mask <<= idx;
        }
}
```

Comment: Suggest `if (idx >= CHAR_BIT)` (or something), else odd `CHAR_BIT` leads to infinite loop.

Comment: and still not working...I miss something...the idea was to keep the even bits and odd bits separated and switch index of even bits to odd bits (vs odd bits to even bits)

Comment: I didn't examine your algorithm, I was just addressing the problem you had with `signed char` vs `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char codeBinPair(char str)
{

    int idx = CHAR_BIT - 1;
    char mask = 1;
    char maskA = 0;
    char maskB = 0;
    // str = 'W'
    while (idx--) // Loop 7 times = 7 bits in char
    {
        //To Replace the odd bits
        maskA |= mask & str;
        mask <<= 1;
        //To Replace the even bits
        maskB |= mask & str;
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    // to shift ths bits of 2 masks 
    maskA <<= 1;
    maskB >>= 1;
    // Subtraction  between the 2 masks will give the encoded
    return maskA - maskB;}

  }
```

Comment: To make this a useful answer, you need to explain what was wrong with the original code and how this version fixes it. Just dumping a bunch of code won't help readers understand.

Comment: You're still using `char` instead of `unsigned char`, so it could be signed, and then your bit operations may not work as expected.

Comment: umm what I was tried to fix in this version its:_to use by 'char' and to take in mask_A the even bits,and to take in maskB the odd bits...and to then shift the even bits to left 1 time and the odd bits to the right 1 time....all what I need to now its to return_maskA |= maskB;

Comment: the problem is when the function will return the char to the main so if I want to use again in this function to get the source char...its not working cuz there is a 1 bit in 7nd or 8nd place in maskA and don't forget its char so its may be -128 and this shit happened me again...I was thinking bout aomthing but its not really working....ty anyway Barmer....